# Why can the resource cannot be found?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, url-routing

I have a asp.net application with the following view directories.

```
-Account
-Shared
  -Layout
-Home
  -index
  -about
-upload
  -uploadindex
  -uploadview
  -Uploaddelete
```

In the Layout I have the fellowing actionlink:

```
     <li class="navbar-links">
@Html.ActionLink("View Uploads", "UploadIndex", "Upload", new { @class = "navbar-links" })
</li>
```

If I am in de home/index page it will go to home/uploadIndex. But when I type in de url http://localhost:12345/upload/uploadindex, then all the actionlink to upload works.

How do I make the actionlinks works from other directory with a other controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A link in MVC (I think you're using MVC) is routed to a controller which invokes a view. A link to `/upload/uploadindex` will by default be handled by the method `uploadindex` on your `UploadController`.

However, `@Html.ActionLink("View Uploads", "UploadIndex", "Upload", new { @class = "navbar-links" })` doesn't do what you think it's doing. That resolves to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.118%29.aspx and the argument `Upload` is understood as the parameter `Object routeParamters`. That creates a link to the "current" controller (in your case `Home`), with route parameter supplied from "Upload" (which get translated to a query parameter `length` with value `6`) for a link to `/Home/UploadIndex?length=6`

You want https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

which would be called as

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Uploads", "UploadIndex", "Upload", new {}, new { @class = "navbar-links" })
```

Here the third parameter is the controller you want the request to be routed to.

Comment: Thx it works now!, But i cannot understand why adding a new (empty) object make this works.

Comment: because it's using the four parameter overload now, which has a "controller" parameter. The three parameter overload doesn't have a "controller" parameter, just a routevalues parameter.